# How to write a function with Oracle regexp to test a domaine name?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I would like to write a PLSQL function that returns true if the domain name I pass is valid.

I should use regular expression, but I don't know how to do this.

```
declare  
  ignore boolean;  
begin  
  isDomainSyntaxOk('www.laclasse.com'); --> should return true.   
  isDomainSyntaxOk('www.la classe.com'); --> should return false because of the space char.  
end;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You'd need to define what is valid and what is invalid. Building the regular expression would be built off of that. Then, use the `REGEXP_LIKE` function to do the check in PL/SQL.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Oracle's regex support didn't start until 10g.  And what about subdomains - IE stackoverflow.com vs blog.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally modified my function to deal with the '..' occurence problem :

```
function isSyntaxeDomaineOk(pStr varchar2, pChar4Space varchar2 default null) return boolean is
begin
    return regexp_like(pStr, '^[a-z0-9][-a-z.0-9]*[a-z0-9]$') 
                              and not regexp_like(pStr, '\.\.');
end isSyntaxeDomaineOk;
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

My regex skills are weak, so I'm hoping that someone comes along and fixes this:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION IS_VALID_DOMAIN (p_DOMAIN IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
  RETURN REGEXP_LIKE(p_DOMAIN, '^[a-z0-9][a-z.0-9]*[a-z]$');
end;
```

Comment: I think this solution is a good begining. it works fine for  : my.domain.com, but not for www.my-domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks for Adam Hawkes' idea. I 've found some regExp that does what I want. The function should return true in these cases :

- only alphanum chars.
- accept '.' and '-' but not at first char and not at last char.

It's should be like this :

```
function isSyntaxeDomaineOk(pDomain varchar2) return boolean is
begin
   return regexp_like(pDomain, '^[a-z0-9][-a-z.0-9]*[a-z0-9]$');
end isSyntaxeDomaineOk;
```